# How to see which partitions are mounted?

Tags: partitions

I want to see if every partition is mounted correctly on my devices; in particular I want to see if the `/proc` gets auto-mounted. How can I see this?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Android Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), you can enter the command `mount` to view what has been mounted.
For a graphical extended view and to view if it gets mounted at boot, you can install the shareware app [EzyMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hokikoki.ezymountcontrol).